# CakePHP: can virtual fields be used in find?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

In the official [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields) I read:

> Do bear in mind that virtual fields cannot be used in finds. If you want them to be part of JSON or array representations of your entities, see Exposing Virtual Fields.

It's not clear to me if the second sentence is in someway related to the first one - say as a workaround to overcome the limitation - or they are completely independent.

I mean: **if I expose a Virtual Field then may I use it in a `find` statement?**

Is there a way to include a virtual field in a query? Here a real example:

ItemOrdersTable.php:

```
$this->setTable('item_orders');
$this->setDisplayField('summary'); // virtual field
$this->setPrimaryKey('id');
```

Entity:

```
protected $_virtual = [
    'summary'
];

protected function _getSummary()
{
    return $this->name . ' ' . $this->description;
}
```

Usage in a Controller:

```
return TableRegistry::get('itemOrders')->find('list')->where(['order_id' => $id]);
```

Because I specified 'summary' as `DisplayField`, I'm expecting a key-value list of all records that meet the where clause, with the `id` as key and the `summary` virtual field as value. Because this doesn't happen (the returned object is null) I'm trying to understand if my code is wrong or I didn't read correctly the documentation as asked above.

Comment: To be clear, the query is actually working because if I set the display field to another field (not virtual) is works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Customize Key-Value Output:**

**https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#customize-key-value-output**

**Update:**

```
$results = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('item_orders')
    ->find('list')
    ->where(['order_id' => $id]);

  debug($results->toArray());
  $this->set('orders', $results);
  debug($orders); exit; <-- test results, and post in your question.
```

Comment: Sorry, I read it a lot of times, but the documentation says: "You can also fetch the label in the list directly using: `$this->setDisplayField('label'); $query = $authors->find('list');` as alternative method to yours.

Comment: Anyway my code is exactly what I reported above but even with your function the virtual field is not shown. Others are shown correctly.

Comment: Whats happen without where clause?

Comment: Same behavior. If I can provide further information feel free to ask. I really don't know what else might matter...